# Adjust div padding with text input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got 4 text inputs

```
Left<input type="text" class="input_box" onKeyUp="show(1,this)"><br />
right<input type="text" class="input_box" onKeyUp="show(2,this)"><br />
top<input type="text" class="input_box" onKeyUp="show(3,this)"><br />
bottom<input type="text" class="input_box" onKeyUp="show(4,this)"><br />
```

and 3 `<div>` containing lot of words. I have to use "`switch`" in JavaScript to adjust the `padding` of div, which class name is "extra". I've already wrote an function `show(inde,obj)` , but it doesn't work.

see exact program HERE: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/jC68G/3/)

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the errors in your console log (In most browsers, F12, then go to Console)

Comment: For a start, the `show` function needs to be defined in the global scope. In jsfiddle, you need to change the second dropdown list from 'onLoad' to 'No wrap' head or body.

Comment: @Curt That is Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByClassName'

Comment: @grc Thanks I made update to my fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some guys were faster :)

As **inn** is contains a set of elements, you need to go through all of them.
And you missed **s**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("extra")
```

I've update [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jC68G/2/).

Answer (score 1):

your sysntax is incorrect

use
`document.getElementsByClassName("extra")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `getElementByClassName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. And, jsFiddle wrap you code in `window.onload = function () { /* you code */}`. So you'll have to use `window.show = function () {}` to define your handler for demos in jsFiddle.

```js
// change this
var inn = document.getElementByClassName("extra");
// to 
var inn = document.getElementsByClassName("extra")[0];
```

Here is the <kbd>[**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VKv9e/)</kbd>